# Jackson Deserialization when new fields added to the POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an object stored in cache in JSON format, it is being serialized using Jackson ObjectMapper. Now I have modified that object with new fields, provided setters and getters for them. When I try to read "old" object from the cache and deserialize it into Java object, I receive Jackson exception:

Error deserializing object of type com....Person.
No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com....Person]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)

How can I avoid this behavior, so that for the new fields default object values will be used?

This is how my pojo looks like after I've modified it by adding new field `phone`.

```
class Person
    {
        private String firstName = "";
        private String lastName = "";
        private int age;
        private String address = "";
        private Integer salary;
        private String phone = "";

        // default constructor required for json/smile serialization
        public Person()
        {
        }

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age, String address, Integer salary, String phone)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.age = age;
            this.address = address;
            this.salary = salary;
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }

        public int getAge()
        {
            return age;
        }

        public String getAddress()
        {
            return address;
        }

        public Integer getSalary()
        {
            return salary;
        }

        public String getPhone()
        {
            return phone;
        }

        public void setPhone(String phone)
        {
            this.phone = phone;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you post your pojo?

Comment: Please find body of my question updated with pojo code

Comment: Isn't your class public?

Comment: no my class is not public, and i do not think i need to make it public since when i remove the new property that i just added everything works just fine.

Comment: Which version of Jackson are you using? This is really strange because it is working for me fine. Maybe, you have changed something else in your source code also?

Comment: @MichałZiober: did you try to deserialize JSON for the object that doesn't contain in it's body one of the class members?

Comment: Yes of course and it works for me. Could you show example JSON which you want to deserialize?

Comment: First off I gonna give this another shot tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: As pointed out above, the missing piece is the old json you're trying to unmarshall.